# How to make a script execute on page load?

Tags: html, random, onload

I am trying to create a HTML script that will pick a random number out of a list I have given when someone loads the page. This means if they refresh the page a new number will appear. I know how to generate a script that shows a random word/number when you press a button but it is necessary to make the number generate itself and also it can't be in a wordbox. If anyone can help me with this, I'd appreciate it.

I don't know much about coding but from the information I've gathered, here's what I have constructed:

```
<html>
<head>
     <title></title>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
// Use the following variable to specify
// the number of random words
var NumberOfWords = 32

var words = new BuildArray(NumberOfWords)

// Use the following variables to
// define your random words:
words[1] = "2,719"
words[2] = "2,718"
words[3] = "2,717"
words[4] = "2,715"
words[5] = "2,713"
words[6] = "2,711"
words[7] = "2,710"
words[8] = "2,709"
words[9] = "2,708"
words[10] = "2,706"
words[11] = "2,704"
words[12] = "2,702"
words[13] = "2,701"
words[14] = "2,700"
words[15] = "2,699"
words[16] = "2,698"
words[17] = "2,696"
words[18] = "2,694"
words[19] = "2,692"
words[20] = "2,690"
words[21] = "2,688"
words[22] = "2,686"
words[23] = "2,685"
words[24] = "2,683"
words[25] = "2,681"
words[26] = "2,678"
words[27] = "2,675"
words[28] = "2,673"
words[29] = "2,671"
words[30] = "2,669"
words[31] = "2,667"
words[32] = "2,664"
function BuildArray(size){
this.length = size
for (var i = 1; i <= size; i++){
this[i] = null}
return this
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", 
function PickRandomWord(frm) {
// Generate a random number between 1 and NumberOfWords
var rnd = Math.ceil(Math.random() * NumberOfWords)

// Display the word inside the text box
frm.WordBox.value = words[rnd]
})
//-->
</SCRIPT>

<CENTER>
<FORM NAME="WordForm">
<INPUT TYPE=TEXT SIZE=50 NAME="WordBox"><BR>
</CENTER>
</FORM>

<body>
<big><big><span style="font-weight: bold;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
<br>
<br>
</span></big></big>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is it doesn't work and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your script inside the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) listener:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
//call your script here
});
```

Note: [IE8 does not support addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Legacy_Internet_Explorer_and_attachEvent).

If you are using `jquery`, you can use [$(document).ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//call your script here
});
```